# Changing connectivity mode in typed dataset

Tags: sql-server-ce

I want to change Mode of connectivity in Typed Dataset.  But I can not change the connection string.  I want it from Read / Write (default mode) to Exclusive to be used on Shared network.

In this topic, you will learn how to set the file mode when you open a Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Compact Edition (SQL Server Compact Edition) database. To set the mode in which the database is opened, you use the mode property in the connection string. The following table defines the valid values for the file mode:

I found following on MS documentation:
Value    Definition
Read/Write
Permits multiple processes to open and modify the database.
Read Only
Lets you open a read-only copy of the database.
Exclusive
Does not permit other processes to open or modify the database.
Shared Read
Permits other processes to read, but not modify, the database while you have it open.
Note:
If you are opening a database that is located on a file share, use the Exclusive file mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add ";File Mode=Exclusive" to your connection string